# How to copy the content of a .NET panel

Tags: c#, forms, panel, draw

I've got a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` in a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. In the panel I draw lines with `myGraphic.DrawLine(myPen, myMouseDownPoint, myMouseUpPoint)`. It works fine so far.

Now I want to show the content of the panel in another `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`. 
But this doesn't work.

What I tried was:

```
this.panel1 = MyForm1.panel1;
this.panel1.Refresh();
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, that the second panel is in a second System.Windows.Forms.Form. I tried this.panel1 = MyForm1.panel1; this.panel1.Refresh();

Comment: Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12463419/edit) below your question to add that information.

Answer (score 2):

1. You won't be able to add the exact same `Panel` instance to several forms.  They are designed to go on one, and only one, `Form`.
2. You are not properly accessing the panel from the other form; it's not (I hope anyway) static, and you don't have an instance of the other form.

What would be best is to make a utility function to generate a `Panel`, and both `Form` instances can call that utility method.

```
public static class UtilityMethods
{
    public static Panel CreatePanel()
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        //do stuff to panel, draw your lines, etc.
        return panel
    }
}
```

There are two important points here.  The first is that each time you call the method you're creating a new panel.  If each `Form` calls the method there will be two separate panels, not one shared panel.  Additionally neither `Form` will need to be accessing the other (it doesn't sound like they should be, from a design point of view).  It makes much more architectural sense for them to both call some 3rd party to do this work.